# Как изменить пути у ссылок на лету не правя html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ссылки

Есть две ссылки, которые должны вести на разные участки ссылки в зависимости от якоря. Необходимые линки я получаю в **link1** и **link2**. Вопрос: как теперь их передать в сами ссылки не правя `html` ?

```js
var link1 = document.getElementsByClassName("link1").href = "link#one";
var link2 = document.getElementsByClassName("link2").href = "link#two";
console.log(link1, link2);
```

```html
<a class="link1" href="link">ссылка1</a>
<a class="link2" href="link">ссылка2</a>
```

Comment: если вы их берете из ссылок, как вы хотите в ссылки же их передавать? они же уже там

Comment: кстати ваш код не работает, так как `getElementsByClassName("link1")` возвращает коллекцию

Comment: @Grundy дополнить налету в сформированный `html`

Comment: @Grundy что означает коллекция? в `console.log` выводит так, как мне нужно

Comment: Коллекция - это **несколько** элементов, а не один, и добавив свойство href в коллекцию, это не значит заменить свойство в конкретном элементе

Comment: В приведенном коде не вижу ни одного использования `console.log`? поэтому нельзя точно сказать, что именно выводится и где

Comment: @Grundy `console.log` добавил

Comment: Вы хотите изменить `href` у элементов `a.link1` и `a.link2` не изменяя её в html документе?

Comment: @Mr_Epic да, все правильно

Comment: @Grundy а, если у меня на странице набор однотипных элементов с одинаковыми классами, каждый из которой выполняет однотипную функцию - применять коллекции можно или нет?

Comment: не понял вопрос. Проблема с коллекциями в данном случае в том, что по ним надо пробежаться и для конкретных элементов выставить свойства, и нельзя сделать так `collection.prop=10` и свойство `prop` установилось у всех.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну если вообще не правя html то вот так:

```js
$('.link1').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  location.href = $(this).attr('href') + '#one';
});
$('.link2').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  location.href = $(this).attr('href') + '#two';
});
```

```html
<a class="link1" href="link">ссылка1</a>
<a class="link2" href="link">ссылка2</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

В приведенном коде, основная ошибка заключается в попытке добавить свойство коллекции, а не конкретному элементу.

Для исправления можно либо использовать `id` вместо класс, либо пробежаться по коллекции в цикле, либо взять первый попавшийся элемент из коллекции, либо использовать [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```js
var link1 = document.getElementById("link1").href = "link#one";
var link2 = document.querySelector(".link2").href = "link#two";
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('link3'), function(el) {
  el.href = "link#three";
})
console.log(link1, link2);
```

```html
<a id="link1" href="link">ссылка1</a>
<a class="link2" href="link">ссылка2</a>
<a class="link3" href="link">ссылка3</a>
```